# Link video (media_youtube) to node

Tags: 7, media

I have a content type called 'webtv' for adding videos from youtube with media, media_youtube modules. On the webtv page I want to add blocks with video preview image and node title.

My problem is that the video preview image is not linked to the node. I followed the instrunctions of the link but is not working as the field in not output to link

https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2011-12-25/making-preview-images-using-modules-media-and-media-for#comment-5644588

I also tried to use Content:Path and add it later but still not working.

PS. file_entity_link is not working because the field is a multimedia asset

Any ideas?

Using media youtube 7.x-3.9 version

Answer (score 0):

The way it worked for me was by adding [path] at the end of the fields of the view and using css (position: absolute).

The best way would be to rewrite the image as link but never worked so I did it by css.